# How to pass in a variable to docker args in a Jenkins declarative pipeline

Tags: docker, jenkins, jenkins-declarative-pipeline

I'm creating a Jenkins declarative pipeline job where I run some node tests within a docker container that depends on an external db container. I create a unique network and then attempt to pass the network uid in as a docker arg so that the docker container can access said db container:

```
def myNetwork = dbNetwork
stage('test-ci') {
      agent {
        docker {
          reuseNode true
          image 'myrepo/my-nodejs'
          label 'docker'
          args "--net ${myNetwork}"
        }
      }
      steps {
          script {
            try {
              sh 'npm run test-ci'
            } catch(err) {
              currentBuild.result = 'FAILED'
            }
          }
        }
    }
```

However, Jenkins output shows that the variable somehow ends up being null by the time docker receives it:

```
$ docker run -t -d -u 233:233 --net null -w /home/jenkins/workspace/es_feature_add-db-container- ...
```

I did note that the example demonstrating passing args uses single quotes, but I need double quotes so `myNetwork` properly expands, but perhaps this isn't the pipeline way.

How can I properly pass a variable to docker?

EDIT: After playing around a little more, I think this is a scope issue since I'm successfully able to pass environment variables like `env.BUILD_TAG`. I basically just need a random, guaranteed unique network name for a given job run so I don't have collisions with other jobs - `env.BUILD_TAG` seems to do the job, but I'd still like to know why I can't pass in a variable that I define in the script.

Comment: If you are trying to connect your app to the database, then consider creating a network and add the db container and app container to this network. Then the app can use the db-container-name as a host name to connect to the db.

Comment: @yamenK - yep, that's exactly what I'm trying to do - I edited to make that a little more clear.

Comment: why don't you use `docker network create` this will create a new network with unique id every time

Comment: Look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44805076/setting-build-args-for-dockerfile-agent-using-a-jenkins-declarative-pipeline i think this is the same problem

Answer (score -1):

Create an `environment` section - this is the way to bridge Groovy and in-Jenkins Shell

```
String SomeVar = "wibble"

pipeline {
...
    environment {
    // use a Groovy GString here
    SomeVar = "$SomeVar"
    // mix with the environment in "shell jenkins" 
    MyBuild = "$SomeVar-$GIT_COMMIT" 
    }
}
 stage(DockerBuild) {
     echo 'this is a groovy level call - so' +  env.SomeVar  + 'will work'
 }
```

In short we can have a variable in Grtoovy segment, and in the pipeline portion still access it in Shell *and* if we need to use groovy level calls (usually docker.build) the varible is in env.Varname