# Image permission in jenkins docker agent

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, cypress

I am using normal jenkins installation (NOT THE DOCKER IMAGE) on a normal AWS ec2 instance, with docker engine installed along side jenkins.

I have a simple jenkins pipeline like this:

```
pipeline {
    agent none 
    stages {
        stage('Example Build') {
            agent { docker {
                image 'cypress/base:latest'
                args '--privileged --env CYPRESS_CACHE_FOLDER=~/.cache'
            } } 
            steps {
                sh 'ls'
                sh 'node --version'
                sh 'yarn install'
                sh 'make e2e-test'
            }
        }
        
    }
}
```

this will make the pipeline fail in the **yarn install** step while installing cypress although all it's dependenices is satisfied from the cypress image.

**ERROR LOG FROM JENKINS**

```
error /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/Devops-Capstone-Project_master/node_modules/cypress: Command failed.

Exit code: 1

Command: node index.js --exec install

Arguments: 

Directory: /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/Devops-Capstone-Project_master/node_modules/cypress

Output:

Cypress cannot write to the cache directory due to file permissions


See discussion and possible solutions at

https://github.com/cypress-io/cypress/issues/1281


----------


Failed to access /.cache:


EACCES: permission denied, mkdir '/.cache'
```

After some investigation i found that although i have provided the environment variable **"CYPRESS_CACHE_FOLDER=~/.cache"** to override the default location in the root directory, and also provided the **"--privileged"**. it fails because for some reason jenkins and docker is forcing their args and user mapping from the jenkins host.

I have also tried providing **"-u 1000:1000"** to override the user mapping but it didn't work.

What could possibly be wrong? and any recommendations or work arounds about this issue?

Thanks ,,

Comment: This is a shot in the dark. Before the error occurs, try using the sh command in your jenkins script to run chmod to open up permissions for the file or directory in question.

Answer (score 0):

I have found a work around by creating a docker file to build the image and pass the jenkins user id and group to it as build arguments, as described here [on this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44805076/setting-build-args-for-dockerfile-agent-using-a-jenkins-declarative-pipeline) .

But this is not guaranteed to work on multiple nodes (master->slaves) jenkins installations as the jenkins user id and group may differ.